# LINQ to SQL, DataBinding, Unit Of Work, and Data Context Management?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

For the past couple of months I have tried to figure out a pattern to manage my Data Context in WinForms applications.

I still don't understand how I can follow the Unit of Work pattern for WinForms application. Some websites proposed maintaining one data context per form, but I encountered several problems with this approach, in particular:

Some of my forms retrieve data from N tables; therefore, with a single context, I'd have to specify a huge amount of eager loading options, causing a gigantic and slow perform SQL query to be generated.

Another problem is that users tend to leave the form open, which could cause the data to get stalled.

In short, what is a good pattern for data context management under WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I've read, the data context is designed to be lightweight so there's not much benefit to keeping them around as far as performance goes.  It's good to keep a connection open for the application, but I generally treat data contexts as very dispensable.

Comment: I tend to keep them around because some forms are the typical "edit->save" and I have to keep the context open until the data is saved back to the database.

Comment: Oh well you may have a hard time following certain design patterns (like Unit of Work) without real business objects.  Right now it sounds like you are treating linq2sql as your business objects rather than using linq2sql to create them.